# Accessing Multiple Trac projects with IIS using isapi_wsgi

Tags: iis, wsgi, trac, isapi

I'm a newbie in the bug tracking system world.

I managed to install Trac 0.12 in Windows Server 2003 and was able to serve the project using IIS through an isapi_wsgi extension using the procedure found here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindowsIisIsapi

I installed the Trac project in `c:\Trac\Project1`, generated the cgi-bin and htdocs directories and placed them in `c:\Trac\Project1\`.

Now I want to create other projects at the same level than Project1 (`c:\Trac\Project2`, `c:\Trac\Project3` and so on).

How can I change the trac_wsgi.py and use URLs as follows: "`http://localhost/Project1`", "`http://localhost/Project2`", and so on?

I have basic experience with IIS and no experience at all with Python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If installation and configuration is you main focus, you'd probably be better off with a different StackExchange site. In this case I propose http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen what seems like a good installation instruction. If I understand correctly, your answer is already in the example given there:

```
# Setup the virtual directories - this is a list of directories our
# extension uses - in this case only 1.
```

So you'll want to register multiple virtual directories by copying the example with a list of directories like so (untested):

```
vd1 = VirtualDirParameters(Name="Project1",
                          Description = "ISAPI-WSGI Trac",
                          ScriptMaps = sm,
                          ScriptMapUpdate = "replace"
                          )
vd2 = VirtualDirParameters(Name="Project2",
                          Description = "ISAPI-WSGI Trac",
                          ScriptMaps = sm,
                          ScriptMapUpdate = "replace"
                          )
...
params.VirtualDirs = [vd1, vd2, ...]
```

I don't know, if you really want to get rid of the `ENV_PARENT_DIR` in the path. Would it hurt to have 'http://localhost/trac/Project1' instead of 'http://localhost/Project1'? This is the common and expected layout of a multiple projects Trac installation. Just my 2ct.

Comment: Would this mean that every time I create a new projet in Trac I would have to recompile the DLL?

Comment: Yes, but what's the problem with that? AFAIK Python re-compiles at launch time any updated script from source file.

Comment: Alright. Good point. One more thing. Is there any way to change the default welcome screen when running multiple Trac projects? I would prefer using some kind of dynamic page that the one simply listing the available project. As I mentionned, I'm not particular familiar with Python. Have any suggestion?

Comment: Well you could use any self-made page, or your own (Genshi) template at least. See the relevant customization options in http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList.